# Using pthreads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, methods, pthreads

I need to use pthreads in C++ but I can't use the function `pthread_create`, it shows me an error. Also, I need to pass multiple parameters to a method:

```
void Read(int socks, int client) {
    while (1) {
        int n;
        char buffer1[256];
        bzero(buffer1, 256);
        n = read(socks, buffer1, 255);
        if (n < 0) {
            perror("ERROR leyendo el socket");
            exit(1);
        }
        cout << "Mensaje de cliente " << client << ":" << buffer1 << endl;
        Jsons json1;
        json1.parseJson(buffer1);
        writeMsg(socks, "hola\n");
    }

}

void ThreadServer::Thread(int sock, int client) {

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid,&attr,Read);

}
```

Comment: When studying something new, the best way to learn is to see an example. Did you see, e.g., LLNL tutorials, something like [Example 2](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#PassingArguments)? Multiple parameters are passed via structures, `pthread_create` takes 4 parameters then.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to send multiple parameters to a thread. The thread functions for `pthread` take a single `void *`.

```
void threadfn(void *data);
```

you just need to create a data structure to hold your parameters

```
 struct threadData
 {
     int param1;
     int param2;
 };
```

declare your struct and assign parameter values. When you call `pthread_create`, pass the struct pointer.

```
struct threadData data = {1,2};

pthread_create(&tid, &attr, Read, &data);
```

when you get the pointer in read function, cast and use it to extract parameters.

```
void Read( void * thrData) 
{
    struct threadData *myParams = (struct threadData*)thrData;
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Ugh. Nasty old C interfaces with `void*` arguments. The world is a much better place with `std::async` and `std::future`.